# How to filter out profiles that have an appointment (foreign key relationship)?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am attempting to retrieve all `Profile` objects that do not have an `Appointment` scheduled. An `Appointment` object may or may not have a `Profile` associated with it (either being an empty time slot or a booked appointment).

I haven't tried anything yet, because I don't know where to start from here.

#### users/models.py

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    objects = managers.ProfileManager()
```

#### booking/models.py

```py
class Appointment(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(
        'users.Profile',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        unique=False,
        null=True,
    )
    massage = models.CharField(
        default=None,
        max_length=2,
        choices=[
            ('SW', 'Swedish'),
            ('DT', 'Deep Tissue'),
        ],
        null=True,
    )
    date_start = models.DateTimeField()
    date_end = models.DateTimeField()
    black_out = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = AppointmentManager()
```

#### users/managers.py

```py
def search_by_name(self, request):
    first_name = request.GET.get('first-name', '')
    last_name = request.GET.get('last-name', '')

    profiles = []
    max_results = 5
    if first_name == '' and last_name == '':
        return (True, {'profiles': profiles})
    elif last_name == '':
        profiles = models.Profile.objects \
            .filter(user__first_name__icontains=first_name)[:max_results]
    elif first_name == '':
        profiles = models.Profile.objects \
            .filter(user__last_name__icontains=last_name)[:max_results]
    else:
        profiles = models.Profile.objects \
            .filter(user__first_name__icontains=first_name) \
            .filter(user__last_name__icontains=last_name)[:max_results]

    return (True, {'profiles': profiles})
```

The `search_by_name` function filters all `Profile` objects containing first and/or last names, including those with an `Appointment` scheduled (which I don't want).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: All `Profile`s that do, or do *not* have an `Appointment`? The title and the question body contradict each other.

Comment: *DO* have. I updated the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain profiles that do *not* have an appointment with:

```
Profile.objects.filter(appointment=None)
```

So you can for example filter with:

```
def search_by_name(self, request):
    first_name = request.GET.get('first-name')
    last_name = request.GET.get('last-name')
    max_results = 5
    filter = {}
    if first_name:
        filter['user__first_name__icontains'] = first_name
    if last_name:
        filter['user__last_name__icontains'] = first_name
    profiles = models.Profile.objects.filter(
        appointment=None,
        **filter
    )
    return (True, {'profiles': profiles})
```